# jQuery plugin multiple instances with incremented variable inside

Tags: jquery, plugins, multiple-instances

I am trying to make a jQuery plugin which will increment and decrement a variable (not a value of an element!). This works, but the multiple instances are incrementing the same variable, and it is not created an isolated value for each.
This is my code:

```
(function( $ )
{

var current_value = 5;
var maxs = 10;
var container_id;

$.fn.moveLeft = function(container_id){
    return this.each(function()
    {
        if (current_value+1 <= maxs)
            {
            current_value++;
            $("#"+container_id).animate({
                marginLeft: "-=194px",
                },200);

            }
    });
    }
$.fn.moveRight = function(container_id){
    return this.each(function()
    {
        if (current_value-1 >= 1)
            {
            current_value--;
            $("#"+container_id).animate({
                marginLeft: "+=194px",
                },200);
            }
    });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

The html part:

```
<div id="back" onclick="$('#back').moveLeft('s1');" >BACK</div><div id="fward" onclick="$('#fward').moveRight('s1');" >FWARD</div>
<div id="s1">SOME CONTENT 1</div>

<div id="back2" onclick="$('#back2').moveLeft('s2');" >BACK</div><div id="fward2" onclick="$('#fward2').moveRight('s2');" >FWARD</div>
<div id="s2">SOME CONTENT 2</div>
```

What i need is to get separate `current_value` for each instance. Can someone guide me? I am new in jQuery...

Comment: what do you mean by each instance

Comment: See the edited question. I have to move "s1" and "s2" separately until "maxs" is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Data) documentation, you can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store state.

```
$.fn.moveLeft = function(container_id) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), moveLeftValue = $this
            .data('moveLeftValue')
            || 5;

        if (moveLeftValue < maxs) {
            $("#" + container_id).animate({
                        marginLeft : "-=194px"
                    }, 200);
            $this.data('moveLeftValue', moveLeftValue + 1);
        }
    });
}
```